# SQL DateAdd to column with UK and US format data

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a column which store the datetime data. But the data could be in US format, UK format or could be some trash data. Thing is i want to try DataAdd to this column. When the data is in UK or US format, then i will DateAdd + 1, otherwise will remain the trash data.

---

Before ===== After

1/30/2018 == 1/31/2018

20.1.18 ==== 21.1.18

N/A ======= N/A

---

**Method 1:**

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(MYCOL) = 1 THEN DateAdd(day,1,MYCOL) ELSE MYCOL END
```

Result: Only the US formate will +1, the UK format will be ignored

---

**Method 2:**

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(Datetime,MYCOL,4)) = 1 THEN DateAdd(day,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),MYCOL,4)) ELSE MYCOL END
```

Result: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string will at the `ISDATE(CONVERT(Datetime,MYCOL,4))` because of the trash data "N/A"

---

**EDITED:**

The trash data will not be only 
"N/A", it could be anything.

Comment: Why note make N/A = Null?

Comment: I dont think there is an answer to this if you have mixed formats. How would you interpret 01/02/18? Or are you 100% sure that US dates in your database have "/" delimiters and UK ones have ".". There is no standard or even convention that says this.

Comment: @TomC, So far , i encounter dd.MM.yy, dd MMM yyyy, MM/dd/yyyy in the column. I foresee there is be new format in the column. So do you suggest i do the dateAdd in my C# code?

Comment: I suggest it is impossible. Unless you know 100% what the user has entered, then it is impossible to determine for days < 13 whether its DD/MM or MM/DD. No point in trying anything else until you can answer this question. Try and get a unique set of formats, and for each see what the number range is for each component. Dates should never, ever be stored in this type of string. And yes - if you have a C# app where the data is written, then enforce date consistency there, and make the data type a date rather than string.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI SQL has date format YYYY-MM-DD, only.

Comment: Fix the data!  Databases support `date` data types for a reason.  If you need to store something other than a date, then use `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
CASE WHEN MYCOL = 'N/A' THEN MYCOL 
     ELSE CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONVERT(Datetime,MYCOL,4)) = 1 THEN DateAdd(day,1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),MYCOL,4)) ELSE MYCOL END
```